# How to set a pixel in a SDL_surface?

Tags: c++, c, graphics, sdl

I need to use the following function from [this page](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL:Tutorials:Drawing_and_Filling_Circles). The [SDL_Surface structure](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_Surface) is defined as

```
typedef struct SDL_Surface {
    Uint32 flags;                           /* Read-only */
    SDL_PixelFormat *format;                /* Read-only */
    int w, h;                               /* Read-only */
    Uint16 pitch;                           /* Read-only */
    void *pixels;                           /* Read-write */
    SDL_Rect clip_rect;                     /* Read-only */
    int refcount;                           /* Read-mostly */
} SDL_Surface;
```

The function is:

```
void set_pixel(SDL_Surface *surface, int x, int y, Uint32 pixel)
{
      Uint8 *target_pixel = (Uint8 *)surface->pixels + y * surface->pitch + x * 4;
      *(Uint32 *)target_pixel = pixel;
}
```

Here I have few doubts, may be due to the lack of a real picture.

1. Why do we need to multiply `surface->pitch` by `y`, and `x` by `4`?
2. What is the necessity of declaring `target_pixel` as an `8-bit integer pointer` first, then casting it into a `32-bit integer pointer` later?
3. How does `target_pixel` retain the `pixel` value after the `set_pixel` function return?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Since each pixel has size 4 (the surface is using `Uint32`-valued pixels), but the computation is being made in `Uint8`. The `4` is ugly, see below.
2. To make the address calculation be in bytes.
3. Since the pixel to be written really is 32-bit, the pointer must be 32-bit to make it a single write.

The calculation has to be in bytes since the surface's `pitch` field is in bytes.

Here's a (less aggressive than my initial attempt) re-write:

```
void set_pixel(SDL_Surface *surface, int x, int y, Uint32 pixel)
{
  Uint32 * const target_pixel = (Uint32 *) ((Uint8 *) surface->pixels
                                             + y * surface->pitch
                                             + x * surface->format->BytesPerPixel);
  *target_pixel = pixel;
}
```

Note how we use `surface->format->BytesPerPixel` to factor out the `4`. Magic constants are not a good idea. Also note that the above assumes that the surface really is using 32-bit pixels.

Comment: may be a pretty basic question, anyhow what does `pitch` represent? and is `surface->pixel` initially pointing to the top-left corner of the window?

Comment: First: first hit on 'google sdl pitch': "Pitch is the width of the memory buffer, which can be larger than the width of the surface." Eloquently stated, can't improve on that. Second: yes. (Any other position would not be useful...)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the code below:

```
unsigned char* pixels = (unsigned char*)surface -> pixels;
pixels[4 * (y * surface -> w + x) + c] = 255;
```

`x` is the x of the point you want, `y` is the y of the point and `c` shows what information you want:

`c=0` corresponds to blue

`c=1` corresponds to green

`c=2` corresponds to red

`c=3` corresponds to alpha(opacity)

Comment: the surface->w is wrong should be used surface->pitch as there could be memory alignement padding (generally divisible by 4) for internal memory optimization